# Deactivate line feed with css of tag p

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm defining a css style and I have a problem with the tag p.
I am defining a style p tag and I get a line feed but I would like to deactivate its Line feed instead. How to do that?

Comment: What are you talking about? How do you "deactivate a line feed"?

Comment: Pikard: Ensign Energize that CSS feed!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I assume you are wanting to prevent multiple `<p>` tags from adding a line-break.  In this event, try `p {display:inline};` to modify the display property.

The preceeding CSS will remove the line-break by default.  Depending on your criteria, you can modify it to reference a specific element or class.

Comment: `p {display:inline;}` is full correct code to deactivate line feed with css of tag p.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean the margin underneath? If so try...

```
p {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: `margin-top: 0;` did it for me.

Comment: Technically it cannot remove the "Line Break"